# Service Account getting error from Calendar API

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I've got two Service Accounts for executing Calendar API requests. 
Both were generated by the same way but it is a small difference between them.
E-mail address of first Service Account ends with "@developer.gserviceaccount.com" and it works.
E-mail address of second Service Account ends with "@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com" and after executing request to Calendar API I get an error:

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Bad Request",
    "reason" : "keyInvalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Bad Request"
}
```

Code example:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();   

 GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                        .setTransport(httpTransport)
                        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                        .setServiceAccountId(service_account_email)
                        .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"))
                        .setServiceAccountUser(user_email)
                        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                            new java.io.File("key.p12")).build();

    Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
            credential).setApplicationName("MyApp")
            .build();

    service.events().list("primary").execute();
```

Any ideas what can be reason of it?

**EDIT:**
The problem occurs also when I try to use Directory API.

Comment: You are using the wrong format of SSL handshake

Comment: So why one of Service Accounts works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was temporary problem with new Service Accounts and Google APIs.
Now all Service Accounts works.